# Индекс находился вне границ массива. Смена регистра

Tags: c#

Смысл кода в том, что он должен заменять первые буквы каждого слова на верхний регистр, но на заходе в цикл for появляется ошибка "Индекс находился вне границ массива"

```
using System;

public class Roflanebalo
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string phrase = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";
        Console.WriteLine(phrase);
        char[] arr;
        arr = phrase.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(arr[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((Char.IsWhiteSpace(arr[i - 1])) && (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(arr[i + 1])))
                {
                    Char.ToUpper(arr[i]);

                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто посмотрите, какие будут перебираться значения i при таком цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
```

`i` тут будет меняться от `0` до `arr.Length - 1`.
Поэтому вылет за границы тут возможен в двух местах внутри цикла (было в трёх местах до редактирования вами кода):

- `arr[i - 1]` когда `i = 0`
- `arr[i + 1]` когда `i = arr.Length - 1`

Вам надо как-то обойти такие ситуации в своём коде, подумайте.
Можно, например, добавить проверку `i > 0` в `if` прежде чем делать что-то с элементом массива `arr[i - 1]`. Конкретный код зависит от того, какую логику вы реализуете своим кодом, что вы хотите чтобы происходило в этом случае.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли